# Best Practice for saving list of connection settings

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I'm searching the best solution for storing the list of connection settings.
In general I know there are different options:

- SharedPrefrences
- Textfile
- SQL Lite

The data structure of the connection looks like this:

- Type of Connection (TCP, FTP, Bluetooth, ...)
- Servername
- Username
- Password

and I have multiple of these above connection settings.

**Pro & Con**

- SharedPreferences: Would be nice to use because android supports automatically updating by using Preference Activities. But SharedPreferences will be stored by a key-value pair. So I have to handle this by defining good keys or storing each connection setting in a new SharedPreferences File.
- Textfile: Difficult to handle with these kind of data.
- SQL Lite: Looks like the best option, but not sure whether it's a lot of overhead storing I have to manage each update of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple rows and columns of data. SQL databases are designed to handle exactly this.

There is no overhead comparing to any other mechanism, where you would have to duplicate some of the database code in your own code.

Comment: yeah, maybe with a combination of ORM for reducing the workload for such a simple cases.

Comment: ORMs have downsides ([Object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch), [The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/)). For simple data like your connection settings list, I recommend you restrict yourself to serialization.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but how up-to-date is this statement. The lecture-list bases on 2006 and older researches.

Comment: I am not aware of any ORM that would solve this (and this would be unlikely because objects and relations are entirely different concepts; anything that maps well to a relational database cannot be object-based).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). Essentially Gson will be creating an XML file that will contain the information that you require. Gson will then be used to save and load that file.

You can create an object or objects to represent the data that you want to store. Here is an example:

```
public interface IConnectionSettings
{
    enum ConnectionType
    {
        TCP, FTP, Bluetooth
    }

    String getServerName();
    String getUserName();
    String getPassword();
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain, I would like to improve my answer or remove it if it is not correct.

Comment: This could be a good option. A positive aspect is also the ability to create easily sample data.

Comment: @Kinimod if the answer helped you please consider accepting it.